# How do I prove this is a field?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Consider the ring of $27$ elements $R = \mathbb{Z}_3[x] = \{a+bx+cx^2\mid a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}_3\}$, where $x^3=x+2$.

I am completely lost on how to prove that this is a field.

Comment: It is enough to prove that $x^3-x-2$ is irreducible.

Answer (score 3):

The polynomial $x^3-x-2$ is irreducible on $\mathbb{Z}/3$ since it does not have any root and its degree is $3$ (a polynomial reducible of degree 3 has a root since one of its factor has degree $1$, just check that $0,1,2$ are not roots.)

Comment: How does this prove that it is a field?

Comment: Because if $R$ is a ring and $M$ a maximal ideal of $R$, then $R/M$ is a field. if $P$ is an irreducible polynomial of $F[X]$ where $F$ is a field, if $Q$ is a polynomial such that $deg(Q)<deg(P)$, then $Q$ is not in the ideal generated by $P$, this implies that the ideal generated by $P,Q$ is $F[X]$ and $1=UP+VQ$, you deduce that $Q$ is invertible in $F[X]/(P)$.

Comment: I think your polynomial should be $x^3-x-2$

Answer (score 2):

You might not have studied this yet, but what you are asking about is really to show that a certain quotient ring is a field.

It is a fact that if $I$ us a maximal ideal in a commutative ring $R$, then $R/I$ is a field. Now in your case your ring is a polynomial ring. An ideal generated by a polynomial $f$ is maximal if and only if $f$ is irreducible. So since $f(x) = x^3 - x - 2$ is irreducible, the ideal $\langle x^3 - x -2\rangle$ is maximal, so 
$$
\mathbb{Z}_3[x] / \langle x^3 - x -2\rangle
$$
is a field. This quotient is exactly what you have when you say that $x^3 - x^2 - 2 = 0$.